# Shell-style function calls?

Tags: javascript, function, operators

I came across a `typeof x` and I'm wondering where this syntax comes from.  I've tried and apparently not just any function can be called w/o parens, like `funcname param`;

So what gives?  What makes `typeof()` different?

Answer (score 2):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/) in javascript that takes one operand. The same way `+`, `-`, `<`, `>` ... are operators.

Answer (score 1):

It is not function it is an operator like echo in php. And there is no many 'types' ("undefined"
,"object", "boolean", "number", "string", "function") in JavaScript, so I think in language without real typing it is not good to use such tools.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, the `typeof` operator is infact quite useful

Comment: Loads, depending upon your scenario. Most common being `typeof x  === 'function'`.